# Create VisualForce Page that creates child case based on query string

Tags: visualforce

I am very new to SalesForce and Salesforce development.  I am trying to create a VisualForce page which takes in a case by query sting using the id key (ie ?id=01p18000000DwhA).  I'd for that VisualForce page all of the user of that page to be able to input only a description.  Once the user clicks save after inputting the description, I'd like for my Apex class extension to create a new child case (with the case that was passed in via query string being the parent class), which has mostly all the same properties as the parent class with only the description being different.

So far I have the following VisualForce page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="ChildPageControllerExtension" sidebar="false" >
    <style>
        .textArea {
            height:200px;
            width:500px;
        }
    </style>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:inputTextarea styleClass="textArea" value="{!case.Description}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

And the following Apex class extension:

```
 public class ChildPageControllerExtension
 {
     public Case child 
     {
         get;
         set;
     }

     public ChildPageControllerExtension (ApexPages.StandardController controller)
     {
         child = new Case();       
     }

     public void Save()
     {
         insert child;
     }
 }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  I'm not quite sure how to continue on from here, but I believe I am close once I figure out how to derive a child case based on the parent case.  Thanks.